# Saxon HE | Call template with param functgion

Tags: templates, param

**why it doesnt work?**

trying to get code template working with param, so far unsuccessfully

```
<xsl:call-template name="template_name" with-param
            name="name"
            select="expression/">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this

```
    <xsl:call-template name="template_name">

        <xsl:with-param
            name="name"
            select="expression">

            <!-- Content:template -->

        </xsl:with-param> 

    </xsl:call-template>
```